# Issue in codeigniter pagination fro first_link and last_link

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pagination

I am using Codeigniter pagination library, its working fine. But i am facing problem in First and last link.

If i put

```
     $config['first_link'] = "First";
     $config['last_link']  = "Last";

     //First < 1 2 3 4 ...12 > Last
```

is working, instead i want to add custom image for first and last link and i tried this code

```
     $config['first_link']  = "<img src='".base_url()."'images/last.png />";
     $config['last_link']   = "<img src='".base_url()."'images/first.png />";

     //image < 1 2 3 4 ...12 > image
```

its not loading the image. When i inspect the element in browser i got this code

```
<img first.png="" images="" src="http://182.72.141.134/estateace/">
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 $config['first_link']  = "<img src='".base_url()."images/last.png' />";
 $config['last_link']   = "<img src='".base_url()."images/first.png' />";
```

I think it was to do with single quot

I hope this would help.